# async / await JS общение с сервером

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, async-await

получил список клиентов с сервера, подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу продолжить работать с data вне области promise?

```
  // Читаем клиентов из базы
  async function fetchGetClients(data) {
    await delay(DELAY_TIME); // установка задержки
    const response = await fetch(URI);


    if (response.ok) {
      data = await response.json();
    } else {
      console.log("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
    }

    return data;
  };

  fetchGetClients().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: «вне области promise» — никак, это принципиально невозможно

Comment: А как мне получить не promise , а объект который в нем находится ? Формально это и есть data.

Comment: @AlekseyShingarev вы его уже и так смогли успешно получить внутри `.then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: @andreymal да, спасибо, понял, то есть всегда вызывать promise когда нужна дата.